# Geospatial queries with Apache Jena

Tags: java, rdf, geospatial, jena

I have problems starting with geospatial querying in Apache Jena.

After receiving a comment from @AndyS, I realised that I needed to create a Spatial dataset from my Jena Model. I still obtain an empty result

First, in my model I have a collection of triples:

```html
<rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
        xmlns:ssn="http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" > 
   <ssn:ObservationValue rdf:about="http://example.com/ObservationValues/GasCO/1450439142">
            <geo:location>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/locations/GasCO/1450439142">
                <geo:lat>35.4</geo:lat>
                <geo:long>32</geo:long>
              </rdf:Description>
            </geo:location>
    <!-- here go more triples -->
    </ssn:ObservationValue>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

I am trying to obtain the ssn:ObservationValue resource using the following code:

```java
String queryStr =
    "PREFIX spatial: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#> " +
    "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
    "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> " +
    "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
    "PREFIX ssn: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#>" +
    "SELECT ?loc " +
    "WHERE {?loc spatial:nearby(35.4 32  1000 'km' )}";

    // creating entity definition. Should somehow define the geodata
    //EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition("ssn:ObservationValue",
    // "geo:location");
    // EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition(" <http://example.com/ObservationValues/GasCO/1450439142>",
    // "<http://example.com/locations/GasCO/1450439142>");
    EntityDefinition entDef = 
    new EntityDefinition("<http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#ObservationValue>",
    "<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#location>");

    // Model m is a Jena Model object which contains the data
    Dataset baseDataset = DatasetFactory.create(m);

    try {
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open( new File("/home/martin/spatial_index"));  
    Dataset spatialDataset = SpatialDatasetFactory.createLucene(baseDataset, dir, entDef); 

            Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr) ;
            QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, spatialDataset);
            ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
            System.out.println("results.size(): " + results.getRowNumber());
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the ResultSet results is empty- the `results.getRowNumber()` returns 0

I suspect the problem with above code is the definition of the `EntityDefinition entDef`. In the documentation of the `EntityDefinition` it states that it expects *entityField* and *geoField* . And I have tried to supply the explicit IRIs of the nodes I am interested in, the prefixed types, e.g. ssn:Observationvalue and geo:location (as suggested by the commented code), but neither solution worked so far.

Had anyone encountered any similar situation or have any hint on what might be wrong?

Comment: Unclear what SemanticSensorModel is.  

There has to be a spatial datasets: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/spatial-query.html else it's just triples.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @AndyS , my bad.
SemanticSensorModel class is a wrapper I have, around the
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model class.

I will look into the link that you supplied- I guess I need to . Also when I make it work, will post the solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was referred to the source code of [spatialindexer.java](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-spatial/src/main/java/jena/spatialindexer.java) by the people from the Apache Jena mailing list. It turns out that I needed to manually add the triples to be indexed into the spatial index. Here I provide the source code with the indexing. It works for me- the above SPARQL query finds triples within the given radius. The modified code is:

```html
String queryStr =
  "PREFIX spatial: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#> " +
  "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
  "PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> " +
  "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
  "PREFIX ssn: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/ssnx/ssn#> " +
  "SELECT ?loc ?lat " +
  "WHERE {?loc spatial:nearby(35.5 32 1000 'km' ) . ?loc geo:lat ?lat}";

Model m = SemanticSensorModel.getIntance().getJenaModel();
EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition("1", "2");    
Dataset baseDataset = DatasetFactory.create(m);
try {
 Directory dir = FSDirectory.open( new File("/home/martin/spatial_index"));
 Dataset spatialDataset = SpatialDatasetFactory.createLucene(baseDataset, dir, entDef); 
   
 DatasetGraphSpatial dataset = (DatasetGraphSpatial) (spatialDataset.asDatasetGraph());
 SpatialIndex spatialIndex = dataset.getSpatialIndex();
 SpatialIndexContext context = new SpatialIndexContext(spatialIndex);
 spatialIndex.startIndexing();
    
 Iterator<Quad> quadIter = dataset.find(Node.ANY, Node.ANY, Node.ANY, Node.ANY);
 for (; quadIter.hasNext();) {
  Quad quad = quadIter.next();
  context.index(quad.getGraph(), quad.getSubject(), quad.getPredicate(), quad.getObject());
 }
 spatialIndex.finishIndexing();
       
 Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr) ;
 QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, spatialDataset);
 ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;

 for ( ; results.hasNext() ; )
 {
  QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
  System.out.println(soln.get("loc").toString() + " " + soln.get("lat").toString());
 }
    
 System.out.println("Done printing results");
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note the creation of the SpatialIndex, and the use of startIndexing()/index()/finishIndexing() methods. 
The above code could be used as a starting point to anybody who
wants to start with geospatial SPARQL queries with Jena.

Regards

Martin